# Increasing sql query performance to compare 2 different rows with using same column than joining another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have a table called `Status`. In this table, there can be 2 records with record status '`A`' and '`O`' for each `c_number`. Many records of each `c_number` are in the `NUMBER` table. The `record_date` field of `c_number's` record with '`O`' in the `Status` table must be greater than the `record_date` of `c_number's` record with '`A'` and the `record_date` must be between the specified dates. In addition, `c_number's` should have a record with a `record_status` of '`1`' in `NUMBER` table. For this, I prepared the following query. How can I improve query performance without indexes? Each table has millions of records.

```
SELECT 
    d.id, 
    d.c_number, 
    d.record_date, 
    dup.record_date 
FROM 
    dbo.STATUS (nolock) as d 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         c_number, 
         record_date 
     FROM 
         dbo.STATUS (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE 
         record_status = 'O' 
         and record_date between '2021-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
         and '2021-07-24 23:59:59.00') dup ON dup.c_number = d.c_number 
                                           AND d.record_status = 'A' 
                                           AND dup.record_date >= d.record_date 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT c_number 
     FROM dbo.NUMBERS (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE 
         status_flag = '1' 
         AND record_date between '2021-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
         AND '2021-07-24 23:59:59.00') cc ON cc.c_number = d.c_number
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: We will need to see at least the query plan and/or the table definitions including any existing keys and indexes and row counts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added sample data for both tables and expected result. Although 0001 has a record in both tables, it will not be listed in the result because its record_date for 'A' is greater than 'O' at status table.

Comment: you sample data should be provided in a way for us to copy and paste

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you understand the consequences, accept the risk of incorrect data or errors, then **at least** use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use a conditional window function to get the result you need, there is no need to self-join.**

Further notes:

- Do **not** use `NOLOCK` unless you don't mind incorrect results. It has serious consequences, only use it if you really know what you're doing
- Instead of `BETWEEN` on dates, use a half-open interval instead `>= AND <`. this means you don't need to mess around working out the last millisecond in the day
- An `EXISTS` or `IN` semi-join is better than a distinct-join in a lot of cases, and gives the compiler more freedom to rearrange the query

```sql
SELECT 
    d.id, 
    d.c_number, 
    d.record_date, 
    oRecordDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        oRecordDate = MIN(CASE WHEN d.record_status = 'O' THEN d.record_date END) OVER
            (PARTITION BY d.c_number ORDER BY d.record_date ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    FROM dbo.STATUS d
) d
WHERE d.c_number IN (
    SELECT cc.c_number
    FROM dbo.NUMBERS cc
    WHERE 
        cc.status_flag = '1' 
    AND cc.record_date >= '2021-07-01'
    AND cc.record_date <  '2021-07-25'
)
AND d.record_date >= '2021-07-01'
AND d.record_date <  '2021-07-25'
AND d.record_status = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to identify if there are any records available in the `NUMBERS` tables, in this case you don't need to join and use `DISTINCT` (this is a costly operation).

Instead, you use `EXISTS`, this will be sufficient.

Check the below query once

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2021-07-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2021-07-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT a_status.id
    ,a_status.c_number
    ,a_status.record_date
    ,o_status.record_date
FROM dbo.STATUS (NOLOCK) a_status
INNER JOIN dbo.STATUS (NOLOCK) o_status ON o_status.c_number = a_status.c_number
    AND o_status.record_status = 'O'
    AND a_status.record_status = 'A'
    AND o_status.record_date >= a_status.record_date
WHERE a_status.record_date BETWEEN @StartDate
        AND @EndDate
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.NUMBERS(NOLOCK) n
        WHERE n.status_flag = '1'
            AND n.record_date BETWEEN @StartDate
                AND @EndDate
            AND n.c_number = a_status.c_number
        )
```